Load a PDF into fabric.js canvas as vector data
I need to load a PDF file into fabric.js without rasterizing.  I've seen lots of solutions (typically involving pdf.js) but they all rasterize the PDF when they have PDFjs render the file to an image - and then import that image into fabric.js.
Is it possible to pass the fabric.js canvas directly to PDFjs for rendering as a vector file?
I am actually most interested in the drawing commands (moveto, lineto, curveto, etc) and I don't really care about text and images in the file.

PDF uses a set of commands that were derived from PS.  As I understand it, PDFjs reads in the PDF content stream parsing operators including lineto, moveto, curveto, etc.  It then calls the 1:1 matching canvas API calls to render the PDF.  PDFjs does not actually have any ability to render a PDF without the canvas doing the real drawing.  I believe fabric.js will 'store' canvas API calls so they can be manipulated and saved later (say as a SVG or JSON).  This 'seems' like it should be the straightforward use of both libraries -- but I'm missing something.

@KJ I appreciate your attempts at helping, but from my perspective, your links support the similarity of PDF to PS and SVG -- changing a command here and there -- or from a stack to a stream (while still expressing lines as lineto moveto curveto commands) is really very similar.  Different would be STEP, PNG, or DXF.  In any case, my question is not about converting the files with 100% fidelity.  My question is about the PDF.js and fabric.js libraries specifically.  If you have specific knowledge of these libraries, please make that clear.

As I understand it, 1) PDFjs parses a PDF file and renders it through a series of canvas API calls.  2) fabric.js can replace the default canvas with a canvas that will record and serialize a set of drawing calls.  It can then work with those entities in memory or save them to SVG or JSON (which is irrelevant to my use).  I don't care (for example) if the original drawing was in a local coordinate system with various transformations applied and the fabricjs version is in global page coordinates.  Differences like that are irrelevant to my application.

I have looked at the docs for fabric.js -- and I have seen that example as one way of getting things done.  The docs also say that fabric will record a set of API calls made to a canvas.

"Is it possible to pass the fabric.js canvas directly to PDFjs for rendering as a vector file?" I dont know all the ins & outs of PDF.js from a code perspective just how dissimilar it is to a real PDF handler. So PDF.js is 3 dynamic "canvases" overlaid. One is a pixelated background export of a PDF rendering. One is a layer of transparent page TEXT exported for selection/read aloud. The 3rd is vector layer for ADDing vectors such as highlights. That seems to be the closest to using HTML as SVG objects. Primarily the canvas that fabric uses for import is let img = new fabric.Image(pdfCanvas
